# How to return a specific error with Observable.error()

Tags: android, unit-testing, exception, rx-java2

I try to test error handling in a content provider using rx. 
Here is a code snippet from the test:

```
 whenever(userInteractor.getUser()).thenReturn(Observable.error(AuthException()))
    val cursor = contentProvider.query(
            uri,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    )
    Assert.assertNull(cursor)
```

Here is a tested code snippet:

```
 } catch (e: AuthException) {
        Timber.e(e)
        return null
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        Timber.e(e)
        val matrixCursor = MatrixCursor(arrayOf("error"))
        matrixCursor.addRow(arrayOf(
                "ConnectionException"
        ))
        return matrixCursor
    }
```

But in this case, always triggers catch for Throwable, not for AuthException. How can I check the case for AuthException?

Comment: How did you know that? Did you put a break points in debugger or?

Comment: The breakpoint does not work. I don't know why. I think that's because of the robolectric test runner. It is a supposition because I can see it in the test. I covered all other possible null returning by tests. Also, I add to getUri method throw Throwable and AuthException lines and in this case, a catch block works correctly